# My iOS Application doesn't show in Settings/Notification Center

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Problem: I have Iphone 6s 64GB, running iOS 8.3, and my app doesn't show in the notification center. I tried all previous suggestions of deleting the apps, turn phone off, then on, wait 5 minutes, reinstall app thru Xcode, launch the app again, and still my app does not show in notification center.
 BTW, I verified that if my app is running in foreground, I could process remote notification correctly.
 Does anyone have this issue. Thanks.

This is my code in AppDelegate.swift.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
        var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        println("..... application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()")


        if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
            // there is a notification...do stuff...
            println("dinFInishLaunchingWithOption().. calling didREceiveRemoteNotification")
            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification as [NSObject : AnyObject])

        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Are there notifications that should be displayed?

Comment: I also tried the suggestions of setting the date/time forward by a few days, then power off/on phone, then installing the app again, and it did not work. Anyone have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: My app is written to receive remote notification, so yes there should be notification banner on top. Weird things is, with another iPhone 6 that I downloaded the same app weeks ago, it was ok and I was able to see the app in notification center. I checked the provisioning in the apple developer certificate site, and it is applied to both of my iPhones.

Comment: Update your question with the code you use to register for remote notifications in the app delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a small issue with your code

```
var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Don't you need to provide `registerForRemoteNotifications` with the notifications you want to register with?

If you look at the documentation for `registerForRemoteNotifications`, it states you need to use `registerUserNotificationSettings:` first.

```
// Calling this will result in either 
// application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: or 
// application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: to be 
// called on the application delegate. Note: these callbacks will be 
// made only if the application has successfully registered for user
// notifications with registerUserNotificationSettings:, or if it is
// enabled for Background App Refresh.
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
func registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I think this is what you should do:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Badge | .Alert | .Sound, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    // Rest of your setup code...        

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    println("Did Register For Remote Notification")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println("Failed to Register For Remote Notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**This information might help if you change the types of registered notifications:**

So iOS stores notification settings for 24 hours after the app is deleted. You could attempt to delete the app wait at least 24 hours then reinstall the app. Then open the App and say Yes to allowing Notifications you can then navigate to your setting and see the notifications settings.

Then only other way I know of to reset notifications settings without waiting for the 24 hour period is wiping the device and not restoring it from a backup.

Once your done with your test then you can restore it from the backup.

Alternatively you could change your app's bundle identifier when testing. It should cause iOS to think of it as a different app.

Comment: Thanks Tobias for your comments. Yes, in my code I do already have those functions didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken() and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError (). I just did not post in the question area.

Comment: Did it work when you added `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)`?

Comment: Thank you Tobia. You nailed it !!  Yes, it worked after I change to use  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings).